# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, maven, junit

I noticed a strange problem. I am able to run my test cases using Junit but when I am running using maven One of the test case is failing. It is complaining that Gson class def is not found.

I am able to see the Gson jar in Maven dependencies.

So I doubted that classpath is not including the Gson. So I ran maven with -X and noticed some clues.

```
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.example.libraries:Symbology:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ra\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for com.example.libraries:Symbology:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[DEBUG] Could not find metadata com.example.libraries:Symbology:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml in local (C:\Users\ra\.m2\repository)
[DEBUG] Skipped remote update check for com.example.libraries:Symbology:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT/maven-metadata.xml, locally cached metadata up-to-date.
[WARNING] The POM for com.example.libraries:Symbology:jar:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available: 2 problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.example.libraries:Symbology:1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.artifactId' for ::jar is missing. @ 
[ERROR] 'dependencies.dependency.groupId' for ::jar is missing. @
```

I have a project which depends on Symbology project and this in turn uses Gson. 
But now from this log I am seeing transitive dependencies are not getting included. So Gson class is not being found.

Here is the Symbology pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.libraries</groupId>
<artifactId>Symbology</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Symbology</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Here is the Pom of my project which is calling symbology :

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.example.libraries</groupId>
<artifactId>FGF</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<distributionManagement>
    <snapshotRepository>
        <id>example.com</id>
        <name>example.com-snapshots</name>
        <url>http://example/artifactory/libs-snapshots-local</url>
    </snapshotRepository>
</distributionManagement>

<name>FGF</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.16</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.libraries</groupId>
        <artifactId>Category</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.libraries</groupId>
        <artifactId>Time</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.libraries</groupId>
        <artifactId>Display</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    **<dependency>
        <groupId>com.example.libraries</groupId>
        <artifactId>Symbology</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>**
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.studio</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.commons.lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>       

</dependencies>
```

Comment: did you try specifying the gson dependency with the <scope>compile</scope>?

Comment: Are those asterisks written on purpose?

Comment: Yes. They are not present in original POM

Comment: @Andrei Sfat  I will give a shot and see

Comment: @Andrei Sfat Same error even after modification

Comment: Have you tried removing the symbology pom and jar from your local maven repository and installing them again?

Comment: Yes, I tried it. No use.

Comment: I tried putting Gson dependency directly in my project pom and all test cases passed. But I dont want to do that. It will be really burst the pom once the project goes bigger.

Comment: If these are your pom.xml files, they are invalid. Aren't they missing the required closing tag for project?

Comment: @ Behe I am sorry. I didnt copy the pom properly. In original pom I have closed project tag. Thanks for poinnting though.

Comment: @ravi, did you manage to fix your problem? Did you try to empty `~/.m2` repository, so it can try to get the dependencies again? Might be one of the cause. Did you try to use the other dependencies to see if you encounter the same problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured Out the Problem Finally after spending lot of time.

The problem is when I am pushing the symbology artifact to repository it is not pushing the pom into repository. So when I am using the symbology artifact as dependency my project is not able to know what are the transitive dependencies.

So I pushed my pom into repository along with jar and now it is able to get all the dependencies.

HURRAYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!