# GSON is not being imported into the maven project

Tags: java, json, servlets, maven, gson

I am getting the following error - I have added the GSon in my dependency -

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong?

[image]

Edit : dependency specified -

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

I am using the following code in my sevlet -

```
 JSONService json = new JSONService();
    String json_output = json.makeLoginJSON(user);
```

makeLoginJSON ---

```
   public String makeLoginJSON(LoginDetails user) {
    String FinalJson = null;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    FinalJson = gson.toJson(user);      
    return FinalJson;       
}
```

Comment: what is your maven dependency declaration?

Comment: what are you using to build your project? And please post your dependency config

Comment: it is accessible, please try to update maven dependencies, if it doesn't work, please try to remove the package from you local maven repository and force it to download again. Try it with a new version could work too.

Comment: you can try explicitly setting the scope of the dependency to 'compile' but i think it should be that by default.  Unless that has been overwritten elsewhere in your setup

Comment: I tried with compile and changing the version.Still giving the same error...

Comment: does eclipse complain?have you tried  `mvn dependency resolve`

Comment: I did dependency:resolve in eclipse...It says SUCCESS..

Comment: I have edited my comment and added a <scope> for the dependency. Please check it now.

Comment: Is it an error you see during maven build or at runtime?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Try:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

I have edited my comment and added the scope. The default scope is *compile*, meaning that the dependency is not present at runtime. For this, you use the *provided* scope. More about scopes in maven dependencies on Apache's [Introduction to Maven Dependencies](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html).

Hope this resolves your issue.

P.S.: if you are creating your own repository, you should also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760667/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-gson-gson).

Comment: Eclipse is not giving me any error...I can do                                        "import com.google.gson.Gson;"

Comment: Did you try to manually add the Gson library to the classpath of the project? So that you get an idea whether it is a problem concerning Maven or not. I am thinking that most probably it is a classpath problem, although Maven should teoretically resolve that (see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4961336/i-am-getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-error-even )

Answer (score 4):

Just a clarification on Raul's answer - good that it works for you, but *provided* is for dependencies that are expected to be available from the JRE/JDK, ie servlet classes. Compile is the default and should work in other people's cases, as gson isn't available from a JRE, instead it needs to be downloaded by maven. From http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Scope:

**compile**
This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

**provided**
This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

**runtime**
This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

**test**
This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.

**system**
This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.

**import** (only available in Maven 2.0.9 or later)
This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the  section. It indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with the dependencies in that POM's  section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Answer (score -1):

Add these import:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
```

Answer (score -3):

Try:

```
<dependency>
     <groupId>com.alibaba</groupId>
     <artifactId>fastjson</artifactId>
     <version>1.1.21</version>
</dependency>
```

Very fast, simple to use.

```
VO obj = ...;
String jsonString = JSON.toJSONString(obj);

VO obj2 = JSON.parseObject(jsonString, VO.class);
```

Comment: Downvoted because this is not an answer to the question.