# Tomcat cannot find gson library ( included via maven )

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, gson

I am trying to include gson in javaEE project with Maven:

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.5</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is my output:

[image]

Project settings:

[image]

Yet it complains :

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson

I am using intelliJ. What is the right way to include it? So far i have only found the output is in correct format...

Thanks for help!

Comment: Maybe you can find an answer here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402633/gson-is-not-being-imported-into-the-maven-pproject

Comment: This didnt work.

Comment: What does mvn compile say?

Comment: it says: package javax.servlet does not exist, same for webservlet annotation, cannot find symbol HttpServlet and so on.

Comment: Could you please share the result of > mvn -X clean install

Answer (score 0):

Can you paste all the pom.xml please, it seems like the javax.servlet reference is missing in tthe pom.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```