# Apache storm - java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson

Tags: java, maven, gson, noclassdeffounderror, apache-storm

I'm using Apache Storm 0.9.4.
I set up a 5 nodes cluster and it works fine.
(Actually 5 supervisors are working as docker containers on 5 different physical nodes.)

My environment is here

---

```
$cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
```

---

```
$docker -v
Docker version 1.4.1, build 5bc2ff8/1.4.1
```

---

```
$java -version
java version "1.7.0_79" OpenJDK Runtime Environment
(rhel-2.5.5.1.el6_6-x86_64 u79-b14) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build
24.79-b02, mixed mode)
```

---

Next, I create a maven project to submit a topology using Netbeans.

There are 1 topology and 1 spout.(very simple)

- MyTopology.java
- LoggerSpout.java

MyTopology works fine without GSON.
But, after I added `Gson gson = new Gson();` in the `nextTuple()` function,
I got java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson.

Here is what I did
 -
 1. `mvn clean` -> `mvn compile` -> `mvn package` -> BUILD SUCCESSFULY
 2. `storm jar ~/Desktop/teststorm/target/teststorm-1.0.jar jp.soushi.teststorm.MyTopology` -> Submitting is OK.

```
Running: /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_80.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java -client -Dstorm.options= -Dstorm.home=/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4 -Dstorm.log.dir=/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/logs -Djava.library.path=/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib -Dstorm.conf.file= -cp /usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/asm-4.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/carbonite-1.4.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/chill-java-0.3.5.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/clj-stacktrace-0.2.2.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/clj-time-0.4.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/clojure-1.5.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/clout-1.0.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/commons-codec-1.6.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/commons-exec-1.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/commons-fileupload-1.2.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/commons-io-2.4.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/commons-lang-2.5.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/commons-logging-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/compojure-1.1.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/core.incubator-0.1.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/disruptor-2.10.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/hiccup-0.3.6.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/jetty-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/jetty-util-6.1.26.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/jgrapht-core-0.9.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/jline-2.11.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/joda-time-2.0.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/json-simple-1.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/kryo-2.21.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/log4j-over-slf4j-1.6.6.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/logback-classic-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/logback-core-1.0.13.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/math.numeric-tower-0.0.1.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/minlog-1.2.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/objenesis-1.2.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/reflectasm-1.07-shaded.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/ring-core-1.1.5.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/ring-devel-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/ring-jetty-adapter-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/ring-servlet-0.3.11.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/snakeyaml-1.11.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/storm-core-0.9.4.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/tools.cli-0.2.4.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/tools.logging-0.2.3.jar:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/lib/tools.macro-0.1.0.jar:/Users/soushi/Desktop/teststorm/target/teststorm-1.0.jar:/Users/soushi/.storm:/usr/local/apache-storm-0.9.4/bin -Dstorm.jar=/Users/soushi/Desktop/teststorm/target/teststorm-1.0.jar jp.soushi.teststorm.MyTopology
491  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Jar not uploaded to master yet. Submitting jar...
499  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Uploading topology jar /Users/soushi/Desktop/teststorm/target/teststorm-1.0.jar to assigned location: storm-local/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-b6added0-ffb8-4602-9d89-b567ed87d335.jar
509  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Successfully uploaded topology jar to assigned location: storm-local/nimbus/inbox/stormjar-b6added0-ffb8-4602-9d89-b567ed87d335.jar
509  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Submitting topology MyTopology in distributed mode with conf {"topology.workers":31,"topology.debug":true,"topology.max.spout.pending":5000}
766  [main] INFO  backtype.storm.StormSubmitter - Finished submitting topology: MyTopology
```

3. I checked the topology using Storm Web UI. After a while, I got NoClassDefFoundError.
4. I edited nimbus.yaml, and add `java.library.path: "/usr/local/lib:/opt/local/lib:/usr/lib:/usr/lib/java"`. and make sure /usr/lib/java can be accessible in the docker container.

Here is the error log(worker-6727.log).

```
2015-04-28T10:05:18.497+0000 b.s.d.executor [ERROR]
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson
at jp.soushi.adcontex.SensorSpout.nextTuple(SensorSpout.java:43) ~[stormjar.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$fn__4654$fn__4669$fn__4698.invoke(executor.clj:565) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:463) ~[storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_79]
... 5 common frames omitted
2015-04-28T10:05:18.564+0000 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Worker died")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Worker died")
at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:325) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at backtype.storm.daemon.worker$fn__5102$fn__5103.invoke(worker.clj:495) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.daemon.executor$mk_executor_data$fn__4555$fn__4556.invoke(executor.clj:240) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at backtype.storm.util$async_loop$fn__458.invoke(util.clj:473) [storm-core-0.9.4.jar:0.9.4]
at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:24) [clojure-1.5.1.jar:na]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_79]
```

- pom.xml
  I tried changing gson's scope(runtime, provided, compile), but it still doesn't work

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>jp.soushi</groupId>
    <artifactId>teststorm</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>teststorm</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <archive>
                        <manifest>
                            <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                            <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                            <mainClass>jp.soushi.adcontex.AdContexTopology</mainClass>
                        </manifest>
                    </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/lib</outputDirectory>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>github-releases</id>
            <url>http://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/github-releases/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>clojars.org</id>
            <url>http://clojars.org/repo</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>local-project-libraries</id>
            <name>Local project libraries</name>
            <url>file://${project.basedir}/lib</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>storm</groupId>
            <artifactId>storm-lib</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

- MyTopology.java

---

```
package jp.soushi.teststorm;
import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.StormSubmitter;
import backtype.storm.topology.TopologyBuilder;

public class MyTopology {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();

    builder.setSpout("Logs", new LoggerSpout(), 5);

    Config conf = new Config();
    conf.setDebug(true);
    conf.setNumWorkers(31);
    conf.setMaxSpoutPending(5000);
    StormSubmitter.submitTopology( "MyTopology", conf, builder.createTopology() );
  }
}
```

- LoggerSpout.java

---

```
package jp.soushi.teststorm;

import backtype.storm.Config;
import backtype.storm.spout.SpoutOutputCollector;
import backtype.storm.task.TopologyContext;
import backtype.storm.topology.OutputFieldsDeclarer;
import backtype.storm.topology.base.BaseRichSpout;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Fields;
import backtype.storm.tuple.Values;
import backtype.storm.utils.Utils;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import java.util.HashMap;

import java.util.Map;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;


public class LoggerSpout extends BaseRichSpout {
    public static Logger LOG = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerSpout.class);
    boolean _isDistributed;
    SpoutOutputCollector _collector;

    public LoggerSpout() {
        this(true);
    }

    public LoggerSpout(boolean isDistributed) {
        _isDistributed = isDistributed;
    }

    public void open(Map conf, TopologyContext context, SpoutOutputCollector collector) {
        _collector = collector;
    }

    public void close() {

    }

    public void nextTuple() {
        Utils.sleep(100);
        Gson gson = new Gson();

        _collector.emit(new Values("Test"));
    }

    public void ack(Object msgId) {

    }

    public void fail(Object msgId) {

    }

    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer declarer) {
        declarer.declare(new Fields("Logs"));
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> getComponentConfiguration() {
        if(!_isDistributed) {
            Map<String, Object> ret = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            ret.put(Config.TOPOLOGY_MAX_TASK_PARALLELISM, 1);
            return ret;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }    
}
```

I found this answer. But I don't understand well.
[java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/gson/Gson](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10760667/java-lang-noclassdeffounderror-com-google-gson-gson)

I also read these answers.

- [Getting java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gson.Gson for maven project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25590303/getting-java-lang-classnotfoundexception-com-google-gson-gson-for-maven-project)
- [GSON is not being imported into the maven pproject](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11402633/gson-is-not-being-imported-into-the-maven-pproject)
- http://www.ciiycode.com/0JSJ6PgUXWxq/javalangnoclassdeffounderror-comgooglegsongsonbuilder-error

I spend 3 days to solve that... I have no idea.
Can anyone provide any solution to this.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try removing `<scope>` and `<type>` tag from your Gson dependency in pom.xml

Comment: Thank you very much. I removed the type element. But it doesn't work well.

Comment: For all people who has the same error. I figured out the correct code. If you have the same error, follow these steps. 1. Edit the pom.xml to remove the <type> element following Neeraj Jain's comment. 2. Change the <scope> to compile. i.e. <scope>compile<scope> following swapyonubuntu's answer. 3. Add the maven-shade-plugin to your pom.xml file following 이승진's answer. I really appreciate people who gave the answers. My topology works well now. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to run topology with fat jar including all the dependency classes which your topology uses. Otherwise, your topology will not be able to find them in runtime.

You've already tried to build fat jar but it's very likely that your jar did not include `Gson`. You can check with `jar tf YOUR.jar` command.

For that purpose, I've been using maven-shade-plugin. 
Refer to : https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: FINALLY, It works well!!!! NO errors with GSON! Thank you for sharing your knowledge. Thank you!!

Comment: Thanks a lot. i was facing this issue from a long time which got resolved now

Answer (score 0):

All cases show one common thing problem is with `<scope>`.

In your case you have provided scope as '**runtime**'.
This means that gson library will not be required while compiling but in runtime, which was not desired .

In your case you need to change your  to **compile**.
ie

```
<scope>compile</scope>
```

**Read more below :**

> There are 6 scopes available:

**compile**

This is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths of a project. Furthermore, those dependencies are propagated to dependent projects.

**provided**

This is much like compile, but indicates you expect the JDK or a container to provide the dependency at runtime. For example, when building a web application for the Java Enterprise Edition, you would set the dependency on the Servlet API and related Java EE APIs to scope provided because the web container provides those classes. This scope is only available on the compilation and test classpath, and is not transitive.

**runtime**

This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

**test**

This scope indicates that the dependency is not required for normal use of the application, and is only available for the test compilation and execution phases.

**system**

This scope is similar to provided except that you have to provide the JAR which contains it explicitly. The artifact is always available and is not looked up in a repository.

**import (only available in Maven 2.0.9 or later)**

This scope is only used on a dependency of type pom in the  section. It indicates that the specified POM should be replaced with the dependencies in that POM's  section. Since they are replaced, dependencies with a scope of import do not actually participate in limiting the transitivity of a dependency.

Comment: Thank you very much. I changed the scope to compile. But It doesn't work well.

Comment: I really appreciate that. It works fine. I changed the scope and added the maven shade plugin. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of the `NoClassDefFoundError` is that the `gson` dependency is not included in your `jar` file and you need to send your topology to your Storm cluster with all the required dependencies in it.

What you want to do is to create a "fat jar". To do so, you are going to need the [Maven Shade plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/). However, you should be careful not to include the `storm-core` dependency in your package, which would conflict with Storm itself.

So, you should add this to your `pom.xml`:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <artifactSet>
                            <excludes>
                                <exclude>org.apache.storm:storm-core</exclude>
                            </excludes>
                        </artifactSet>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Running `mvn package` should now produce a `jar` file that includes all dependencies (except `storm-core`). You can verify this with:

```
jar -tf ~/Desktop/teststorm/target/teststorm-1.0.jar
```